How do i read Touch Coordinates directly from HID using Python
What I want to do is read touch coordinates directly from an external touchscreen connected via USB-C. I want to bypass the OS by directly accessing the HID report. I've tried two libraries:
pywinusb.hid and hid.
This is the device I used for testing:
WingCoolTouch (vID=0x27c0, pID=0x0858).
I've also tried my gaming mouse with the same result.
import hid

# Replace with your device's Vendor ID and Product ID
VENDOR_ID = 0x046d
PRODUCT_ID = 0xc07e


def read_hid_device():
    # Open the HID device
    try:
        device = hid.Device(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
        print(f"Opened device: {device}")
        
        while True:
            # Read data from the device (set the size as needed)
            data = device.read(64)  # Read up to 64 bytes from the device
            if data:
                print("Data received from HID device:", data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to open device: {e}")
    finally:
        device.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_hid_device()

The result being an opened device with some address, but no matter how hard I press the touchscreen, I do not get any prints or errors.
I tried deactivating the driver in the device manager to rule out interference from windows. This caused the device to not function at all in windows (as you would expect). After dis- and reconnecting the touch device it now controls the mouse courser but still no print in my code.
Also i tested my Gamingmouse as HID Input and got similar results.
